# AHK Pixelgetcolor changing coordinates inside a loop

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I'm in need of help with some logic issues that might be very much simple and I just can't get my head around. I need to compare different coordinates in my screen with a static value given on a variable. Like:

If (StaticColor = ColorInCoordinate) {

Run this

}

But I need to run that 8 times on different coordinates to check if everything is running fine. Is there any other easier way than simply running the GetPixelColor 8 times inside the Ifs?

Comment: You mean `PixelGetColor`? What is wrong with running it 8 times?

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays:

```
StaticColor = 0x113322
coords := [ {x:122,y:112}
          , {x:464,y:589}
          , {x:163,y:673}
          , {x:173,y:457}
          , {x:245,y:986}
          , {x:264,y:567}
          , {x:252,y:922}
          , {x:556,y:773}]

Loop, % coords.MaxIndex() 
{
    currentX := coords[A_Index].x
    currentY := coords[A_Index].y
    PixelGetColor, ColorInCoordinate, currentX , currentY
    If (ColorInCoordinate = StaticColor) 
    {
        ;Run this
    }
}
```